# Where does Mac OS X store the information about previously connected Bluetooth devices?

Tags: macos, macbook, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

Where does Mac OS X, specifically 10.6 Snow Leopard, store its information about Bluetooth mice and keyboards that have been connected before?

I ask because last night I reinstalled Snow Leopard from a clean install. I then copied my previous home directory to a directory called "Old Home Directory". This evening I connected to my travel Apple Wireless Mighty Mouse only to notice that it listed both my travel and office desktop mice. The weird thing is that since reinstalling Snow Leopard, I haven't connected to my office mouse (unless somehow while at work my MacBook detected my desktop mouse as I was in my office but didn't use the mouse). However, it does not list my desktop Apple Wireless Keyboard. I'm at a loss as to why my office desktop mouse is listed but not my office desktop keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.5, there is a preference file at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` which contains a key `RecentDevices`. I imagine that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't have the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` file. However, I do have the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` file, and it does list both mice. It shows the last name update as of 3:30PM today. I guess the OS scanned and found the desktop mouse but not my desktop keyboard while I was at work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.